# How to change font colour and size of Python Shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, colors, size

I am using Python 3 and I am not sure if this is a possible query because I've searching it up and I couldn't find a solution. My question is, I want to learn how to change colour and size of my output.

How to make the size bigger or smaller?

> > > Able to make the font size big

How to change the background colour of shell?

> > > Able to make the background colour, for example, right now, it's all white but I want it black.

How to change the output colour of shell?

> > > I would love to see colourful fonts operating in black background shell

I hope there is a solution to this! Thanks in advance

Comment: You can make the shell bigger by simply pressing `command + '+'` and the shell offers a few color options which you can edit in the `config` file. More info on that here: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/ipython.html

Comment: Depends on what shell? Idle? Terminal? Cmd? Pycharm? Pydev? Which one?

Comment: due to "bg white", I'd say it is idle.

Comment: -abccd the shell that opens when I run python IDLE

Answer (score 1):

I know about the color part, but I came for the size.
To start off with, to close the color, use `\u001b[0m`. If you don't use  this, all text will become the color that you started with until you close it. 
Green is`\u001b[32m`
Black is`\u001b[30m`
Pink is `\u001b[35m`
There are much more, but is you experiment with different numbers, you can highlight and do different colors.
To make a sentence with color, format it like this:
`print("\u001b[35mHi, coders. This is pink output.\u001b[0m")`
Test that code. it will come out in pink.